# How to loop in r?

Tags: r, for-loop

I spent a whole day now trying to get familiar with the (for) loop function in r but I didn't find a solution for my problem.

I want to perform the following computation for 27 countries without having to type in the code again and again.

```
percentageAT_leakingroof <- length(c11dep$hh040[c11dep$hh040==0 & c11dep$db020=="AT"]) / length(c11dep$hh040[c11dep$db020=="AT"])

percentageBE_leakingroof <- length(c11dep$hh040[c11dep$hh040==0 & c11dep$db020=="BE"]) / length(c11dep$hh040[c11dep$db020=="BE"])
```

Is it possible to write a loop that computes the percentages for the following 27 levels? (And is it also possible to name them correctly? "percentageAT_leakingroof", "percentageAT_leakingroof", etc.)

```
levels <- c("AT", "BE", "BG", "CH", "CY", "CZ", "DE", "DK", "EE", "EL", "ES", "FI", "FR", "HU", "IT", "LT", "LU", "LV", "MT", "NL", "PL", "PT", "RO", "SE", "SI", "SK", "UK")
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Try with `sapply/lapply` i.e. `lst <- lapply(levels, function(x) length(c11dep$hh040[c11dep$hh040==0 & c11dep$db020==x])/length(c11dep$hh040[c11dep$db020==x])); names(lst) <- paste0('percentage', levels,'_leakingroof'); lst`

Comment: It may be also easier to do with `table` and `prop.table`.  A reproducible example would be helpful

Answer (score 2):

check out the [dplyr](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) package. It's perfect for this kind of tasks.

```
library(dplyr)

c11dep %>%
    group_by(db020) %>%
    summarise(percentageAT_leakingroof = sum(hh040==0) / n())
```

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails:

```
for(n in 1:27){
  write(paste0("percentage", levels[n], "_leakingroof <- length(c11dep$hh040[c11dep$hh040==0 & c11dep$db020==\"", levels[n], "\"]) / length(c11dep$hh040[c11dep$db020==\"", levels[n], "\"])", "tmp.R")
  source("tmp.R")
  file.remove("tmp.R")
}
```

Get R to write and then execute the code for you!  Use `\"` for the double quote marks.

Answer (score 0):

Although I would also recommend using `dplyr`, with a `for` loop you could do something like this to print the results:

```
for (i in levels) {
  length(c11dep$hh040[c11dep$hh040==0 & c11dep$db020==i]) / length(c11dep$hh040[c11dep$db020==i])
}
```

The assignment part is a bit trickier. A list is an easy start:

```
results <- list()
for (i in seq_along(levels)) {
  results[[levels[i]]] <- length(c11dep$hh040[c11dep$hh040==0 & c11dep$db020==levels[i]]) / length(c11dep$hh040[c11dep$db020==levels[i]])
}
```

Or if you want vectors with the naming scheme you have, incorporate `assign` to the loop:

```
for (i in seq_along(levels)) {
  res <- length(c11dep$hh040[c11dep$hh040==0 & c11dep$db020==levels[i]]) / length(c11dep$hh040[c11dep$db020==levels[i]])

  # String for the vector name you want
  vec_name <- paste0("percentage", levels[i], "_leakingroof")

  assign(vec_name, res)
}
```